# Drop Down Search Results Filter in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, filter, scope, drop-down-menu

I am new to Rails and trying to filter search results by a drop down menu. The drop down is biketype (ie 'Road', 'Mountain'), which is an attribute of the bike model. I would then also like to sort by price.

My index view:

```
<% form_tag(bikes_path, :method => :get) do %>
<%= select_tag( :biketype, options_for_select(Bike::BIKETYPES) )%>
<%= submit_tag "Submit" %>
<% end %>
```

And my bikes_controller for the location-based search (used geocoder):

```
   def index 
     @title = "Bikes"
       if params[:search].present?
         @bikes = Bike.near(params[:search], 50, :order => :distance).paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 9)
       else
         @bikes = Bike.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 9)
       end
   end
```

If you had any suggestions as how to update my controller and model to get the filter and sort that would be great. I've been recommended scopes but not sure how to implement them. Thanks so much, Will.

Comment: Just curious, do you remember where and how `Bike::BIKETYPES` was defined? I'm also trying to add a dropdown to filter search results.

Answer (score 1):

```
class BikesController < ApplicationsController

   def index 
     @title = "Bikes"
     @bikes = Bike.near_search(params[:search]).\
                paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 9)

   end
end


class Bike  

  def self.near_search(params)
    if params
      near(params, 50, :order => :distance)
    else
      all
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: Nice refactoring. But do you know how to implement the above drop down form as a :biketype attribute filter on the bike index? Thanks!

Comment: I can't see your rest code, but you can do iterate by a constant with **scope^* creation. class_eval do; BIKETYPES.each do |b|; scope b.to_sym, where(:type, b); end.

Comment: you can use **order('price DESC')** to sort the collection by price

Comment: So the scope would be in the bike model but then how do you invoke it using the drop down? Is my view correct? And is the order('price' DESC') in the model as well? Sorry, first time with scopes. Thanks for the help!